# difference between iterator and enumeration

Tags: java, collections, iterator, enumeration

see the below code

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Modification_On_Eumeration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>();
        vector.add(1);
        vector.add(2);
        System.out.println(vector);
        Enumeration<Integer> enumeration = vector.elements();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.print(integer);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("first loop finished");
        vector.add(3);
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            Integer integer1 = (Integer) enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println(integer1);
        }
    }
}
```

the above code is working fine and the output is:

```
[1, 2]
12
first loop finished
3
```

now see the below code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class Fail_Safe_Iterator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> copyOnWriteArrayList=new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>();
        copyOnWriteArrayList.add(6);
        copyOnWriteArrayList.add(2);
        System.out.println(copyOnWriteArrayList);
        Iterator<Integer> iterator=copyOnWriteArrayList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
        System.out.println("first loop finished");
        copyOnWriteArrayList.add(5);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(integer);//why not printing 5
        }
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
[6, 2]
6
2
first loop finished
```

I am learning java..my doubt is in the fist example after adding 3,I am able to retrive and print it.but in the second example after adding 5 I am unable to retrive and print it.what is the reason ?
is it due to iterator fail safe behaviour ? or  is it one of the difference beween enumeration and iterator? help me....

Comment: Using Iterator over Enumeration is preferable, there is no need to use Enumeration anymore.

Comment: I am not asking , what to use..

Comment: So that's why I've added comment not answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` creates a new `Iterator` based upon the current state of the underlying array that backs the list.

**Java Source**

```
 public ListIterator<E> iterator() {
         return new COWIterator<E>(getArray(), 0);
 }
```

This iterator does not contain the element added after its creation because the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`performs mutative operations (add, set, and so on) by making a fresh copy of the underlying array.  Therefore, when you create an iterator it is reflection of the underlying array at that instant.

**Fix**

```
    System.out.println("first loop finished");
    copyOnWriteArrayList.add(5);

    //get the new iterator after adding
    iterator = copyOnWriteArrayList.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer integer = (Integer) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(integer);//why not printing 5
    }
```

Comment: Just wanted to reiterate that you need understand the difference between the objects you were using to iterate, and how, once you added a new element to a list, you needed to get a fresh reference to your iterator.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `Iterator` has a `.remove()` operation whereas an `Enumeration` doesn't.

Also, we are in 2014, so don't use `Vector` nor `Enumeration`; they are obsolete and only legacy APIs still use them.

As to why your program behaves this way, this is due to the "copy on write" of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`: the iterator is created with the *current* list contents; if you modify that list after you have created your iterator, you won't see the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you used `CopyOnWriteArrayList` class:

from java doc of CopyOnWriteArrayList:

> The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of
>   the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never
>   changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is
>   impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException. **The iterator will not reflect
>   additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was
>   created.** Element-changing operations on iterators themselves (remove,
>   set, and add) are not supported. These methods throw
>   UnsupportedOperationException